# Normalization in Scikit-learn KNN

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, classification, knn

I want to use KNN Algorithm in Sklearn. In KNN it's standard to do data normalization to remove the more effect that features with a larger range have on the distance. What I wanted to know, is that is this automatically done in Sklearn or I should normalize the data myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not automatically done in sklearn. However sklearn provides [tools to help you normalize your data](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html), which you can use in sklearn's [pipelines](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html).